# How do I fix the if condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to satisfy all the following conditions but Yr1,Yr2 and Yr3 are not columns. It is excel sheet names.

```
if df["Grades"]>="D": and Yr1>=27 and Yr2>=27 and (Yr1+Yr2) >=60 and Yr3>=27:
    print("True")
```

error shows

```
Invalid comparison between dtype=float64 and str
```

how do i fix this.

Comment: Have you tried `df["Grades"]>=1.00`? Also, what's with that first `:`, that should give a syntax error before anything else.

Comment: Can you give a minimal example of how your excel sheet look like?

Comment: yes same error shows

Comment: The excel file has 3 sheets names Yr1,Yr2,Yr3.Each page has course code , number of credits offers by each course and Grade column. i want to check all the grades should be above D or equal and Yr1 total number of credits greater than or equal to 27

Answer (score 0):

I think the value of "df["Grades"]" is in float. But in the condition, you are using string. Try something like this,

```
if df["Grades"]>=1.00 and Yr1>=27 and Yr2>=27 and (Yr1+Yr2) >=60 and Yr3>=27:
    print("True")
```